# R- How to edit repeated records?

Tags: r

I'm reading data from a csv. This is what my data looks like. There are some records that have the same label/question on different days. **I want to add numbers to the repeated questions.**

```
UserID Full Name  DOB     EncounterID Date   Type  label                          responses    
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          1-1-21   Intro Check Were you given any info? (null)
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          1-2-21   Intro Check Were you given any info?  no
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          1-3-21   Intro Check Were you given any info?  yes
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          1-6-21   Intro Check Were you given any info?  no
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          1-6-21   Care  Check By using this service..   no
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          1-6-21   Out   Check How satisfied are you?    unsat
```

Desired output (I would like to add numbers to the repeated questions as you can see below):

```
UserID Full Name  DOB     EncounterID Date   Type  label                          responses    
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          1-1-21   Intro Check Were you given any info?1 (null)
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          1-2-21   Intro Check Were you given any info?2 no
1      John Smith 1-1-90  13          1-3-21   Intro Check Were you given any info?3 yes
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          1-6-21   Intro Check Were you given any info?  no
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          1-6-21   Care  Check By using this service..   no
2      Jane Doe   2-2-80  14          1-6-21   Out   Check How satisfied are you?    unsat
```

Comment: Please post your sample data using `dput(x)`, it's a bit difficult to grab that data with embedded spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(UserID, label) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = row_number(), 
         label = if(sum(newcol)> 1) paste0(label,newcol) else label) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-newcol)
```

Or more straight as suggested by r2evans (many thanks!):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(UserID, label) %>% 
  mutate(label=if (n() > 1) paste0(label,row_number()) else label)
```

```
  UserID Full.Name  DOB    EncounterID Date   Type  label                           responses
   <int> <chr>      <chr>        <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>                           <chr>    
1      1 John Smith 1-1-90          13 1-1-21 Intro Check Were you given any info?1 (null)   
2      1 John Smith 1-1-90          13 1-2-21 Intro Check Were you given any info?2 no       
3      1 John Smith 1-1-90          13 1-3-21 Intro Check Were you given any info?3 yes      
4      2 Jane Doe   2-2-80          14 1-6-21 Intro Check Were you given any info?  no       
5      2 Jane Doe   2-2-80          14 1-6-21 Care  Check By using this service..   no       
6      2 Jane Doe   2-2-80          14 1-6-21 Out   Check How satisfied are you?    unsat
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(UserID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Full.Name = c("John Smith", 
"John Smith", "John Smith", "Jane Doe", "Jane Doe", "Jane Doe"
), DOB = c("1-1-90", "1-1-90", "1-1-90", "2-2-80", "2-2-80", 
"2-2-80"), EncounterID = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L), Date = c("1-1-21", 
"1-2-21", "1-3-21", "1-6-21", "1-6-21", "1-6-21"), Type = c("Intro", 
"Intro", "Intro", "Intro", "Care", "Out"), label = c("Check Were you given any info?", 
"Check Were you given any info?", "Check Were you given any info?", 
"Check Were you given any info?", "Check By using this service..", 
"Check How satisfied are you?"), responses = c("(null)", "no", 
"yes", "no", "no", "unsat")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Couldn't you `mutate(label = if(n()> 1) paste0(label,row_number()) else label)`? The grouping is a natural flow for this data, nice.

Comment: Great r2evans. Will update my answer! Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I get the following error when using the second solution though ```Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function"```

Comment: @AshS Have you tried with the data supplied by my answer? I do not get an error!

Comment: Yes I tried it with your data and I still get that error @tarjae

Comment: Please open a new question with the complete code!

Comment: BTW: the error (`applied ... "function"`) is likely because you tried this code *verbatim*, not realizing that we had to *guess* at the name of your data, so TarJae stored it in a **d**ata**f**rame named `df`. It's an unfortunate convenience, though, since if your object is not named that and you don't update the answer to reflect your variable name(s), then `df` is a base-R function.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```r
ave(dat$label, dat[c("UserID", "label")],
    FUN = function(z) if (length(z) > 1) seq_along(z) else "")
# [1] "1" "2" "3" ""  ""  ""
```

which can be used as

```r
dat$label <- paste0(dat$label,
 ave(dat$label, dat[c("UserID", "label")],
     FUN = function(z) if (length(z) > 1) seq_along(z) else "")
)
#   UserID  Full.Name    DOB EncounterID   Date  Type                           label responses
# 1      1 John Smith 1-1-90          13 1-1-21 Intro Check Were you given any info?1    (null)
# 2      1 John Smith 1-1-90          13 1-2-21 Intro Check Were you given any info?2        no
# 3      1 John Smith 1-1-90          13 1-3-21 Intro Check Were you given any info?3       yes
# 4      2   Jane Doe 2-2-80          14 1-6-21 Intro  Check Were you given any info?        no
# 5      2   Jane Doe 2-2-80          14 1-6-21  Care   Check By using this service..        no
# 6      2   Jane Doe 2-2-80          14 1-6-21   Out    Check How satisfied are you?     unsat
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(UserID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), Full.Name = c("John Smith", "John Smith", "John Smith", "Jane Doe", "Jane Doe", "Jane Doe"), DOB = c("1-1-90", "1-1-90", "1-1-90", "2-2-80", "2-2-80", "2-2-80"), EncounterID = c(13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14), Date = c("1-1-21", "1-2-21", "1-3-21", "1-6-21", "1-6-21", "1-6-21"), Type = c("Intro", "Intro", "Intro", "Intro", "Care", "Out"), label = c("Check Were you given any info?", "Check Were you given any info?", "Check Were you given any info?", "Check Were you given any info?", "Check By using this service..", "Check How satisfied are you?"), responses = c("(null)", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "unsat")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```